# Ubuntu vs lubuntu for desktop?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, desktop-environments

Are the UI and speed of operation the only differences ? I want to know if the functionality is the same or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean of functionality?

Lubuntu is an Ubuntu OS with the same repository sources, but with a different desktop environment and set of default applications (packages).

In the matter of desktop, you can also install LXDE and its components on Ubuntu either to try it beside Gnome Shell (Unity on 17.04 and below).